# Calculating average daily returns with For-Loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to put my script into a For-Loop in order to calculate the mean daily return for multiple stocks.

But when I setup the For-Loop I get the following error:

> Error in getSymbols(Symbols = stock, src = "yahoo", from = "2005-01-01",  : 
>     must use auto.assign=TRUE for multiple Symbols requests

So I removed `env = NULL` and replaced it with `auto.assign=TRUE` but when I run the script I get `NaN` as a result.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
install.packages('quantmod')
library(quantmod)

stock <- c("AAPL") 
{
stock.xts <- getSymbols(Symbols = stock, src = "yahoo", 
                       from = "2005-01-01",
                       to = "2019-09-10", 
                       env = NULL)

stock.xts <- as.data.frame(stock.xts)

N <- nrow(stock.xts)
todays.price <- stock.xts[2 : N,4]
yesterdays.price <- stock.xts[1 : N-1,4]
stock_dailyreturn <- (todays.price - yesterdays.price)/yesterdays.price
stock.xts$daily.return <- c(NA,(todays.price - yesterdays.price)/yesterdays.price)
print(mean(stock_dailyreturn)) 
}
```

With the For-Loop:

```
stock <- c("AAPL", "MSFT", "CRM", "ORCL", "NFLX", "GOOG")

for(i in 1:length(stock)){
  stock.xts <- getSymbols(Symbols = stock, src = "yahoo", 
                          from = "2005-01-01",
                          to = "2019-09-10",
                          auto.assign = TRUE)
  stock.xts <- as.data.frame(stock.xts)

  N <- nrow(stock.xts)
  todays.price <- as.numeric(stock.xts[2 : N,4])
  yesterdays.price <- as.numeric(stock.xts[1 : N-1,4])
  stock_dailyreturn <- (todays.price - yesterdays.price)/yesterdays.price
  stock.xts$daily.return <- c(NA,(todays.price - yesterdays.price)/yesterdays.price)
  print(mean(stock.xts$daily.return))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were super close! 
Give this a try this instead:

- change your for loop to hold an individual value through each iteration (seen in the for loop below)
- update the use of the getSymbols function so that it autoassigns properly (otherwise it defaults to NULL - check the documentation for more info)
- use a placeholder vector for the getSymbols function to create objects in (I just called it hello for now

Good luck!

```
stock <- c("AAPL","MSFT","CRM")

hello <- c()

for(value in stock){

stock.xts <- getSymbols(Symbols = value, src = "yahoo",
                    from = "2005-01-01",
                    to = "2019-09-10",
                    env = hello,
                    auto.assign=TRUE)
stock.xts <- as.data.frame(stock.xts)

N <- nrow(stock.xts)
todays.price <- stock.xts[2 : N,4]
yesterdays.price <- stock.xts[1 : N-1,4]
stock_dailyreturn <- (todays.price - yesterdays.price)/yesterdays.price
stock.xts$daily.return <- c(NA,(todays.price - yesterdays.price)/yesterdays.price)
print(mean(stock_dailyreturn))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entire issue is in the last line of code, `mean(stock.xts$daily.return)`, and the line directly before it. `mean` by default returns `NA` or `NaN` if the vector averaged over contains an `NA` value, `stock.xts$daily.return <- c(NA, ...`. This can be changed by setting `na.rm = TRUE` within mean.

However your loop can be further reduced in complexity. First of all, you are importing your symbols in every iteration. This is unnecessary. Also you can utilize the `diff` and `lag` function, to calculate your returns by using `diff(...)/lag(...)`.

For example you could use something similar to the example below:

```
library("quantmod")
stock <- c("AAPL", "MSFT", "CRM", "ORCL", "NFLX", "GOOG")
#Create a place to store the symbols
stockenv <- new.env()
stuff <- getSymbols(Symbols = stock, src = "yahoo", 
                   from = "2005-01-01",
                   to = "2019-09-10",
                   env = stockenv) #<=== note here, i import into the environment
ls(stockenv) #<== check that all the symbols were imported into the environemnt.
#[1] "AAPL" "CRM"  "GOOG" "MSFT" "NFLX" "ORCL"
priceChange <- vector("list", length(ls(stockenv)))
meanPrice <- vector("list", length(ls(stockenv)))
#overwrite names
names(priceChange) <- names(meanPrice) <- ls(stockenv)
for(i in ls(stockenv)){
    priceChange[[i]] <- diff(stockenv[[i]][,4]) / lag(stockenv[[i]][,4])
    meanPrice[[i]] <- mean(priceChange[[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
}
simplify2array(meanPrice)
#        AAPL          CRM         GOOG         MSFT         NFLX         ORCL 
#0.0012548717 0.0013114559 0.0008412977 0.0005783129 0.0019348552 0.0005236143
```